# Android java, Side drawer menu is showing up whenever the app is launched and the app is getting crashed on closing the menu

Tags: java, android

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No drawer view found with gravity LEFT

at com.example.books.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:245)

The terminal shows that the error is with the onOptionsItemSelected function

I have referred many StackOverflow posts regarding errors with side navigation drawer but I couldn't find the solution

Logcat

```
 2022-05-08 17:13:15.175 867-867/com.example.books E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.books, PID: 867
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No drawer view found with gravity LEFT
    at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.openDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1736)
    at androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout.openDrawer(DrawerLayout.java:1722)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.toggle(ActionBarDrawerToggle.java:287)
    androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:245)
    at com.example.books.MainActivity.onOptionsItemSelected(MainActivity.java:245)
    at android.app.Activity.onMenuItemSelected(Activity.java:4324)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onMenuItemSelected(FragmentActivity.java:352)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onMenuItemSelected(AppCompatActivity.java:264)
    at androidx.appcompat.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onMenuItemSelected
    at androidx.appcompat.widget.ToolbarWidgetWrapper$1.onClick(ToolbarWidgetWrapper.java:188)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:8160)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:8137)
    at android.view.View.access$3700(View.java:888)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:30250)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8443)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:596)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout


xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_gravity="left"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/dl">

<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout

android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<SearchView
    android:id="@+id/searchView"
    android:layout_width="277dp"
    android:layout_height="34dp"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:background="@drawable/bg_white_rounded"
    android:iconifiedByDefault="false"
    android:queryHint="Search book,title,author, etc.."
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.119"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.035"
    app:queryBackground="@drawable/bg_white_rounded"
    app:submitBackground="@drawable/bg_white_rounded"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

</SearchView>

<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView2"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="10dp"
    app:contentPadding="@dimen/cardview_default_elevation"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.131">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/idIVCourseImage5"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_width="76dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bookdonation" />

</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.136"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.131">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/idIVCourseImage1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="0dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/onlinepurchase" />
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


<androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/cardView3"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    app:cardElevation="8dp"
    app:cardMaxElevation="10dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.865"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.131" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/idIVCourseImage2"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_width="96dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/prouddonars" />
</androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView7"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="FICTION AND NON-FICTION BOOKS"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.115"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.519" />

<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/idRVCourse"
    android:layout_width="403dp"
    android:layout_height="333dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.961"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView9"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/inter_medium"
    android:text="Purchase books"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.122"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.276" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fontFamily="@font/inter_medium"
    android:text="Donate books"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.498"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.276"
    android:clickable="true"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView11"
    android:layout_width="89dp"
    android:layout_height="17dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/inter_medium"
    android:text="Proud donars"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.869"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.275" />


<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

</LinearLayout>

<HorizontalScrollView
    android:id="@+id/horizontalScrollView"
    android:layout_width="407dp"
    android:layout_height="148dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.401"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="408dp"
            android:layout_height="136dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardMaxElevation="10dp"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="99dp"
                android:layout_height="99dp"
                android:src="@drawable/medical"></ImageView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="210dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="MEDICAL HEALTH AND SCIENCE BOOKS"></TextView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"

                android:text="Biochemistry| Physiotherapy | Phathalogy"></TextView>


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonmed"
                android:layout_width="68dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/inter"
                android:text="Order "
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="10sp" />


        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="408dp"
            android:layout_height="136dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardMaxElevation="10dp"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/fictionandnonfiction"></ImageView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="210dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="EXPLORE THE WIDE RANGE OF FICTION AND NON FICTION"></TextView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:text="Science Fiction| Short stories | Teens"></TextView>


            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttoneng"
                android:layout_width="68dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/inter"
                android:text="Order"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="10sp" />


        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>


        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="408dp"
            android:layout_height="136dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardMaxElevation="10dp"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/ncert"></ImageView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="210dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text="NCERT BOOKS FOR CLASS 1-12"></TextView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:text="Physics| Chemistry | Mathematics"></TextView>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonfiction"
                android:layout_width="68dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/inter"
                android:text="Order"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="10sp" />


        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="408dp"
            android:layout_height="136dp"
            android:elevation="10dp"
            app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
            app:cardMaxElevation="10dp"
            app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="true"
            app:cardUseCompatPadding="true">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="96dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/competative"></ImageView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="210dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:text=" WIDE RANGE OF AVAILABLE COMPITATIVE EXAM BOOKS"></TextView>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="110dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
                android:text="Banking| UPSC| SSC"></TextView>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/buttonfinance"
                android:layout_width="77dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:fontFamily="@font/inter"
                android:text="Order"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textSize="10sp" />


        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
    </LinearLayout>
</HorizontalScrollView>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView5"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.777"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.048"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_favorite" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView7"
    android:layout_width="36dp"
    android:layout_height="29dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.045"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/cart1" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView8"
    android:layout_width="32dp"
    android:layout_height="27dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.889"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/linearLayout"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.048"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_location" />


   <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="match_parent"
  android:id="@+id/idnav_bar"
  android:layout_gravity="left"
  android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
  app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
  app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu"
  tools:ignore="InvalidId,MissingConstraints" />
  </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
  </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Mainactivity.java

```
  package com.example.books;

  import android.content.Intent;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.view.Gravity;
  import android.view.Menu;
  import android.view.MenuItem;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.widget.Button;
  import android.widget.ImageView;
  import android.widget.TextView;
  import android.widget.Toast;
  import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

  import com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView;
  import com.synnapps.carouselview.CarouselView;
  import com.synnapps.carouselview.ImageClickListener;
  import com.synnapps.carouselview.ImageListener;

  import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
  import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBar;
  import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
  import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
  import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
  import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
  import androidx.recyclerview.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
  import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
  import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;
  import java.util.ArrayList;
  import android.view.MenuItem.OnMenuItemClickListener;
  import java.util.Objects;



  import org.w3c.dom.Text;



  public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   private Button button;
   private Button medbutton;
   private RecyclerView courseRV;
   public DrawerLayout dl;
   private Toolbar toolbar;
   public ActionBarDrawerToggle abdt;
   public TextView TVdonars;
   public TextView TVdonatebooks;
   public TextView TVpurchasebooks;
   public ImageView wishlistimg;



   private ArrayList<CourseModel> courseModelArrayList;




    private int[] mImages = new int[]{
        R.drawable.academic, R.drawable.engineering, R.drawable.medical, R.drawable.fiction

    };
    private String[] mImagesTitle = new String[]{
        "Academic", "Engineering", "Medical", "Fiction"
    };



   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Classic Books Donar");
    medbutton = findViewById(R.id.buttonmed);
    wishlistimg = findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
    //button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    courseRV = findViewById(R.id.idRVCourse);
    TVpurchasebooks = findViewById(R.id.textView9);
    TVdonatebooks = findViewById(R.id.textView10);
    TVdonars = findViewById(R.id.textView11);


    TVdonatebooks.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Register.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
    TVdonars.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Prouddonars.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });

    TVpurchasebooks.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Purchasebooks.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

    });
    final NavigationView nav_view = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.idnav_bar);
    nav_view.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new 
    NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.select_catogery) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Select Catogery", 
        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }


            if (id == R.id.engineering) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Engineering", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            if (id == R.id.medical) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Medical", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return true;
        }
       });




    dl = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.dl);
    abdt = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, dl, toolbar, R.string.open, R.string.close);
    abdt.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);

    //Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    //setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    dl.addDrawerListener(abdt);
    abdt.syncState();

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);


 

    courseModelArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    courseModelArrayList.add(new CourseModel("Design of Machine Elements, Fourth Edition", "V 
    B Bhandari", R.drawable.designofmachineelements));
    courseModelArrayList.add(new CourseModel("Fluid Mechanics, Sixth Edition", "Munsun, 
    Okilshi,Huebsch & Rothmayer", R.drawable.fluidmechanics));
    courseModelArrayList.add(new CourseModel("Fundamentals of Thermodynamics", "Claus 
    Borgnakke & Richard E Sonntag", R.drawable.thermodynamics));
    courseModelArrayList.add(new CourseModel("Shigley's Mechanical Engineering Design", 
    "Richard G Budynas & JJ Keith Nisbett", R.drawable.mechanicalengineeringdesign));
    courseModelArrayList.add(new CourseModel("Atlas of Human Anatomy, Seventh Edition", "Frank 
    H. Netter, MD ", R.drawable.atlasofhumananatomy));
    courseModelArrayList.add(new CourseModel("Data structures and algorithms", " Alfred V.Aho, 
    John E.Hopcroft, Jeffrey D.Ullman", R.drawable.datastructures));
    courseModelArrayList.add(new CourseModel("Textbook of Clinical Neuroanatomy, Third 
    Edition", "Vishram Singh ", R.drawable.clinicalneuroanatomy));

    // we are initializing our adapter class and passing our arraylist to it.
    CourseAdapter courseAdapter = new CourseAdapter(this, courseModelArrayList);

    // below line is for setting a layout manager for our recycler view.
    // here we are creating vertical list so we will provide orientation as vertical
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, 
    LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);

    // in below two lines we are setting layoutmanager and adapter to our recycler view.
    courseRV.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    courseRV.setAdapter(courseAdapter);


    medbutton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Medical.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    wishlistimg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Wishlist.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
   int id = item.getItemId();
   if (abdt.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
       return true;
   }
   return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
  }
  }
```

Comment: A `DrawerLayout`'s drawer must be a direct child of it. Move your `<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView>` to after the closing `</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>`, so that it's directly inside the `<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>`.